# Issue with WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c++, memory

I wanted to learn a bit how does game hacking work, so I have made a simple game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    int score = 100;
    int* address = &score;

    SetConsoleTitle(L"Simple game");
    cout << "Address of score is " << address << endl;
    cout << typeid(address).name() << endl;
    for (; ;) {
        cout << score << ' ' << address << endl;
        score = max(score - 1, 0);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Just value decreasing to zero. Also it writes address of this score for easier changing.
This is my "hack":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    HWND handle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Simple game");
    DWORD processId;

    if (handle == NULL) {
        cerr << "No such window" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Window handle: " << handle << endl;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &processId);
        cout << processId << endl;
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, processId);

        if (!hProcess) {
            cerr << "Couldn't find window";
        }
        else {
            int writeResult = 0;
            int val = 2000;
            writeResult = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x00DAFC58, (LPCVOID)val, sizeof(val), NULL);
            if (writeResult == 0) {
                cerr << "Declined" << endl;
                cerr << GetLastError() << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Success" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that this code is written not in a perfect form, sorry. It gives me Error 299. As I understand, this means partial execution of writing process. I think that the problem is in second argument of WriteProcessMemory, lpBaseAddress. What is my mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi agamemdon, check how to set permissions to access a different process memory, also there can be other causes, there was a topic about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799195/writeprocessmemory-error-partial-copy-299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at where you have written `(LPCVOID)val`. This is the address of the memory you want to copy from in your process. 2000 is probably not a valid address. You want to copy from the `val` variable itself, so you should use its address, `&val`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such insulting mistake.